# Java IF statement requiring multiple inputs

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm working on a four function calculator for java (yes I know I'm wasting my time, I'm just getting used/into java.) It takes the first two inputs fina and add/subtracts/etc them, and outputs that as an answer, and I attatched a while loop after that answer so the user can input as many more numbers as he would like.

```
while(finalanswer == 0){
        System.out.println("If finished, type 'done'.");
        System.out.println("To change your operation, type 'change'. Otherwise, enter your next number.");
        if(calc.next().equals("done")){
            finalanswer = 1; break;
        }else if(calc.next().equals("change")){
            System.out.println("'addition', 'subtraction', 'division', or 'multiplication'?");
            userOperation = calc.next();
        }else{
        modanswer = calc.nextDouble();
        if(userOperation.equals("addition")){
            System.out.println(answer += modanswer);
        }else if(userOperation.equals("subtraction")){
            System.out.println(answer -= modanswer);
        }else if(userOperation.equals("division")){
            System.out.println(answer /= modanswer);
        }else{System.out.println(answer *= modanswer);}
    }
    }
```

That is the loop that allows the user to add more inputs if he wants, but when I try and add a number I have to type two other numbers first (which have no effect as far as I've seen) and then the third number is finally input and added to the original answer.

Comment: `if(calc.next().equals("done")){...}else if(calc.next().equals("change")){...` you are reading input twice if first condition is false. Consider storing result of `next()` before using it on your conditions.

Comment: why would you be wasting your time by making a calculator in java  if it helps you learn the syntax of the language? Also what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is below the code block. And thank you, how would I go about storing the results?

Comment: String input = calc.next(); and in if condition use it like if(input.equals("done"))......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained briefly by Pshemo, the `calc.next()` function asks the user to input something, and returns the input. In this code, `calc.next()` is called three times in each cycle of the while loop. If the first input isn't "done", it continues. If the second input isn't "change", it continues, and the third input (obtained through `calc.nextDouble()`) is assigned to `modanswer`.

You need to store the value of `calc.next()` as a separate variable to avoid having to read the input three times:

```
while(finalanswer == 0){
    System.out.println("If finished, type 'done'.");
    System.out.println("To change your operation, type 'change'. Otherwise, enter your next number.");
    String input = calc.next();
    if(input.equals("done")){
        finalanswer = 1; break;
    }else if(input.equals("change")){
        System.out.println("'addition', 'subtraction', 'division', or 'multiplication'?");
        userOperation = calc.next();
    }else{
    modanswer = Integer.parseInt(input);
...
```

Note that you need to use `Integer.parsInt()` to convert the String obtained through `calc.next()` into an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Pshemo said, you have to store `calc.next()` before you check the different conditions:

```
String tmp = calc.next();

if(tmp.equals("done")){
      finalanswer = 1; break;
}else if(tmp.equals("change")){
      System.out.println("'addition', 'subtraction', 'division', or 'multiplication'?");
      userOperation = calc.next();
}else{
.
.
.
```